# How to map two member fields as an Object?

Tags: java, dozer

I am new to [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). I started to explore the same to avoid writing java code to map between Objects.

I have the following use case:

```
class ObjectA {
 private String ab;
 private BigDecimal cd;
 private Long ef;
 ...
}

class Object B {
 private Amount zy;
 private Long xw; //ef ->xw
}

class Amount {
 private BigDecimal value; //cd -> value
 private String code; //ab -> code
 // Contains a static method to initialize an instance
}
```

How do I write a custom converter that accepts cd & ab and returns an instance of Amount? And how do I call it from the mapper? A sample custom converter for multiple fields to a single field will suffice too!

UPDATE: I solved my problem by writing custom converters for the two classes(A and B). I am leaving the question open since I was actually looking for a way to handle this at a field level rather than the class level.

Comment: I have no idea what Dozer is, but the title seems confusing. I don't see any primitive fields here.

Comment: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Dat code obsfuscation in the question ;) Could you at least name your variables in human readable form eg. currencyName, ammount ? It would sow what you want to do right away..